# Equivalent characterization of inner direct sum of subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a vector space and let $A, B$ be subspaces of V.
The **sum** of $A, B$ is the subspace of $V$ given by
$$
  A + B = \{a+b : a\in A, b\in B\}
$$
Moreover if $A \cap B=\{0\}$ then the sum of $A,B$ is called the **inner direct sum of $A,B$** and is denoted with $A \oplus B$.
Let $A, B, C$ be subspaces of $V$ with $C = A + B$. 
Then
$$
  C = A \oplus B
  \iff
  \forall c \in C, \exists! a\in A, \exists! b \in B : c = a + b
$$

> If we replace on the right hand side $\forall c\in C$ with $\exists c\in C$ then does the equivalence still hold?

Comment: Your question does not seem to be clear.

Comment: Take $A \cap B = \{0\}$ and $C = A$, then for any $c \in C$ (in particular: $\exists c \in C$ s.t. ...) there are unique $a \in A$ and $b \in B$ s.t. $c = a + b$, namely $a = c$ and $b = 0$, but $C \neq A + B$, hence $C = A \oplus B$ is not true.

Comment: @qwertz i restated my quastion because it was not clear enough. Thank u very much for your answer

Comment: @nature1729 u are right. I restated my question.

Comment: What is the meaning of '!' ?

Comment: @AnyAD unique. So $\exists !$ means there is EXACTLY ONE

Answer (score 1):

The equivalence still holds:
We have that
\begin{align*}
  C = A \oplus B
  &\iff
  \forall c \in C, \exists! a\in A, \exists! b \in B : c = a + b
  \\
  &\,\implies
  \exists c \in C, \exists! a\in A, \exists! b \in B : c = a + b
\end{align*}
because we can choose $c = 0$.
To show the other implication
$$
  \exists c \in C, \exists! a\in A, \exists! b \in B : c = a + b
  \implies
  \forall c \in C, \exists! a\in A, \exists! b \in B : c = a + b
$$
let $c \in C$ such that for $c = a + b$ with $a \in A$, $b \in B$ the summands $a, b$ are unique.

Let $x \in A \cap B$.
It then follows from $x \in A$ that $a + x \in A$ and it follows from $x \in B$ that $b - x \in B$.
We have that
$$
    c
  = a + b
  = (a + x) + (b - x)
$$
so it follows from the uniqueness of $a, b$ that $a+x = a$ and $b-x = b$.
Both equations show that $x = 0$.
This shows that $A \cap B = \{0\}$ and together with $C = A+B$ that $C = A \oplus B$.

For subspaces $A, B, C \subseteq V$ with $C = A + B$ one can show more generally that the following conditions are all equivalent:

- $C = A \oplus B$, i.e. $A \cap B = 0$
- $\forall c \in C: \exists! a \in A \exists! b \in B: c = a + b$
- $\forall c \in C: \exists! a \in A \exists b \in B: c = a + b$
- $\forall c \in C: \exists a \in A \exists! b \in B: c = a + b$
- $\exists! a \in A \exists! b \in B: 0 = a + b$
- $\exists! a \in A \exists b \in B: 0 = a + b$
- $\exists a \in A \exists! b \in B: 0 = a + b$

Comment: You are excellent